# Unable to compile setup file of PyMedTermino-0.3.3

Tags: python-3.x, bioinformatics, biopython, medical, snomed-ct

I am trying to compile setup.py file of PyMedTermino-0.3.3.
Getting an this message
 error:package directory '.\utils' does not exist
after typing python destination_folder\setup.py build
getting this output
[image]

any suggestion will be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you are trying to build `PyMedTermino` yourself. I don't know what caused your error, but since `PyMedTermino` is also available on [PyPi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyMedTermino), you can also install it with `pip`:

```
>pip install PyMedTermino
Collecting PyMedTermino
  Downloading PyMedTermino-0.3.3.tar.gz (34.0MB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 34.0MB 262kB/s
Building wheels for collected packages: PyMedTermino
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for PyMedTermino ... done
  Stored in directory: C:\Users\jeroen\AppData\Local\pip\Cache\wheels\71\01\91\f3ec03bdc7c10c11093b77f8a5ecef4f855327c1b29107d4dd
Successfully built PyMedTermino
Installing collected packages: PyMedTermino
Successfully installed PyMedTermino-0.3.3
```

Comment: Thanks for the info.If I install PyMedTermino directly by pip install how I will set the path for SNOMED CT,SNOMEDCT_CORE_SUBSET,ICD10.As I know these files are not readily available in PyMedTermino.

Comment: You set the global parameter [`pymedtermino.DATA_DIR`](http://pythonhosted.org/PyMedTermino/tuto_en.html#loading-modules-and-setting-global-parameters) to point to the directory where the SQLite3 database files (like `snomedct.sqlite3` ) are located.

Comment: After installing PyMedTermino I have put snomedct.sqlite3 in proper path.I have also edit setup.py of installed package and set path for SNOMEDCT_DIR,SNOMEDCT_CORE_FILE,ICD10_DIR. After that When I tried to  execute SNOMEDCT.search("Cardiac structure") ,it shows an error  OperationalError: no such table: Description_fts

Comment: No idea how to solve that. Maybe [create an issue](https://bitbucket.org/jibalamy/pymedtermino/issues/new) at the [PyMedTermino issue tracker](https://bitbucket.org/jibalamy/pymedtermino/issues)?